# How to access virtual hosts on Mac with tethered iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, apache

I have several of my development web sites on my Mac, each set up as virtual hosts in Apache.  For example: example.dev, example2.dev, example3.dev.  (I know we're not supposed to use .dev anymore, but I'll do that for my next project.)

I have an iPhone tethered via USB and would like to access the *.dev sites via Safari for testing.

I can access Apache's main directory via the Mac's IP address or .local, but I can't figure out hot to get to the virtual hosts; it throws a 404.  Is there a way to get the iPhone to use the same DNS settings as the Mac?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to install `dnsmasq` on your mac. 
First install dnsmasq:

```
brew install dnsmasq
```

Run the configuration command it asks you to, which may look similar to this:

```
cp /usr/local/opt/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.conf.example /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

Now you can edit the configuration at /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf. Add the following line: (I put mine right below the line that says "#address=/double-click.net/127.0.0.1")

```
address=/*.dev/192.168.1.10
```

192.168.1.10 is your private ip address

Now restart the dnsmasq service

```
sudo brew services restart dnsmasq
```

Hope this works for you.